# Text with break lines not working in Rails

Tags: css, mysql, ruby-on-rails, gmail, webmail

I have an AngularJs + Rails.

I have a form with a text field where the user can write whatever text with break lines. When the user submits the form the message stored in db and sent by email to another user. The email sent should keep the line breaks.

The point is the format of the message is working perfectly in production. However it has stopped working in development. Aparently, we haven´t done a specific update in the code that affects this, but we are migrating our Rails and mysql to a newer version at the moment in development. So, I wonder if it´s related to this, however, am not able to see where exactly the problem is.

Please let see the two different behaviours with an example:

We will send the same sample message in both environmets, so in our textarea we write:

```
This is a test message

with a some break lines.

Lorem ipsum whatever.
```

This is the text message that is sent to be stored in a varchar field in my mysql database: `This is a test message\n\nwith a some break lines.\n\nLorem ipsum whatever.`

This is the text that I can see stored in both development and production database: `This is a test message  with a some break lines.  Lorem ipsum whatever.`

This is the template to send the email in both development and production (no changes here): `<p class="p1" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"><%= @offer.message_pre_offer %></p>`

This is the log that I see when the message is sent by email in development:

```
<p class=3D"p1" style=3D"white-space: pre-wrap; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0=
; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #606=
060; font-family: Source Sans Pro, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans=
-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 150%; font-weight: 300;" align=3D"l=
eft">This is a test message=0D
=0D
with a some break lines.=0D
=0D
Lorem ipsum whatever.</p>=0D
<style>=0D
```

Unfortunately I cannot see this detailed log in production because the debug level is not set to debug.

When I open the email that the test user is got in gmail in webmail, this is the code that I can see in dev tools in Chrome:

Development working wrong:

```
<p style="white-space:pre-wrap;margin:1em 0;padding:0;color:#606060;font-family:Source Sans Pro,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:150%;font-weight:300" align="left">This is a test message



with a some break lines.



Lorem ipsum whatever.</p>
```

This is how it looks in gmail webmail:
[image]

Production working fine:

```
<p style="color:#606060;font-family:Source Sans Pro,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:15px;font-weight:300;line-height:150%;margin:1em 0;padding:0;text-align:left;white-space: pre-line;" align="left">This is a test message

with a some break lines.

Lorem ipsum whatever.</p>
```

This is how it looks in production:
[image]

Probably it´s not related at all, buy my rails versions are:

- Development: Rails 5.2.4, mysql 8.0.18
- Production: Rails 4.4.0, mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

Comment: TLDR but I think I have got the gist of the issue. Try reading about these `String` class methods: `to_json`, `as_json`. One more thing: if you save a string in rails enclosed in `<pre>` tag (`like "<pre>This is my string</ pre>"`), it keeps everything html, this may work for your case too or there must be similar solution.

Comment: Your <pre> approach is not working. I get the same result but just with different font-family style. Regarding to_json, I don´t know where do you want to go. If you think this is the solution please provide more details.

Comment: @Rober as you have told, you are migrating system ( MySql, Rail ) do you mean your production is at old version and you have started migrating on development ?

Comment: Correct! I have just noticed that when I wrote the post I missed the mysql development information. But you can find details of both enviroment version just at the bottom of the post.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to explain the extra vertical spacing:

Windows uses CR LF for line breaks.

Unix systems use LF.

Macintosh uses CR.

When you display one form of line break on a system that is expecting a different form, a mess can occur.

Perhaps the "right" design uses only LF, then changes or expands as needed depending on the target machine.  Note that `<br>` is the equivalent for HTML, where CR and LF are simply "white space".

See also `<pre>` and PHP's `NL2BR()` and probably other things.

Answer (score 0):

What templating engine are you using to generate the emails, and do the inlining of CSS?

I suspect that's related to the problem here, because the `style` output for development and production differ in the examples you've given.

In particular, development has `white-space: pre-wrap` and production has `white-space: pre-line`. This is important because `pre-line` will condense multiple newline characters into a single newline, whereas `pre-wrap` will preserve all of them.

---

This hopefully explains why you are seeing different behaviour in production vs development, but you likely want to preserve all whitespace that the user types in. In this case, you can ensure consistent spacing by replacing instances `\r` and `\r\n` with just `\n`

e.g. `user_input.gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n")`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would love to say you found it. The different white-space style that you see in development and production is just a small mistake while testing, but unfortunately nothing happens when you try the diffenrent options pre-wrap or pre-line.

Comment: Regarding the second comment, if you read the description carefully, you can read that I´m sending this text: This is a test message\n\nwith a some break lines.\n\nLorem ipsum whatever to the database. So, I´m using just \n as you suggest. I send the email in both development and production and open it in the same laptop in Mac. So, the only difference is the servers that are running dvevelopent under Mac and production under Ubuntu. So, I would point the parsing of the message in the server?